# How to share LinkedIn profile edits?

Tags: linkedin, sharing

I know that you can choose whether you want to share LinkedIn profile edits or not. You might want to disable sharing when you make some small changes, and you might want to enable it if you want to share that you have a new job.

I want to share a profile edit. I go to `Me` - `Settings & Privacy` - `Privacy` - `Profile privacy`. There you have

> Sharing profile edits
>
> Choose whether your network is notified about profile changes

Although I have selected 'Yes', when I go to my profile and click on a pencil to edit an experience, it displays

> Your edits above won’t be shared with your network.

Why is this the case? How can I share it however? I searched on Google but I only found the information that you can enable/disable it in the settings (which does not seem to work in my case).

Comment: Are you able to see the change in **See all activity**?

Comment: @serenesat I do not think so.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, it's a known issue... LinkedIn has been "working on it" for more than a month, with no word to users other than that. 
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/496565

Comment: Update: I tried again today and it seems that the issue is not solved.

Comment: Update: I tried again today and I do not see the aforementioned message ('won't be shared') anymore. Instead, there's the same switch as in the settings to choose between sharing and not sharing. If it turns out that the issue is resolved indeed, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Update: I tried again today. When editing a part of your profile, there is the same switsh as in the settings to choose between sharing and not sharing. But if you edit the information, the switch is replaced by the aforementioned message ("won't be shared"), before you can validate your edit.

Comment: Following the link mentioned in your answer, I read that you can only share a new profile entry. I am trying to share a modification to an already existing entry. Should that not be possible? I remember to have obtained messages that say that person x has finished his master's degree y.

Comment: I tried to add a new entry, but I immediately obtain the "won't be shared" message on the bottom of the edit window. Verified that sharing of profile edits in settings is on.

Answer (score 2):

you need to go to "me", then click "edit your public profile" and then also tick the box on the right side of the page "send updates to network".

**Customize Your Public Profile**
Control how you appear when people search for you on Google, Yahoo!, Bing, etc.
Learn more
Make my public profile visible to no one
**Make my public profile visible to everyone**
Basics (required)

Comment: Thank you for this information but it does not solve my question. It allows me to choose which part of my profile is visible outside of LinkedIn. What I want to do is to inform my LinkedIn followers of an edit I made to my profile -- which is not working, see Question above.